# setTimeout function always triggers

Tags: jquery, settimeout

I'm using the following code to hide a div (named info) when you click outside of it:

```
$(document).click(function(e) {
if (e.target.id != 'info' && !$('#info').find(e.target).length) {
        $("#info").fadeOut(300);
setTimeout(function() {
        $("#info").html("Select an Item");
},300);
}; //if statement
}); //click function
```

What i'm trying to achieve is after the fadeOut is done, to place the text "Select an Item" in the div. However this SetTimeout is always executed; the div shows itself through another function, but it seems that this setTimeout function also triggers, immediately.

Why does this happen and how do you fix this?

Comment: Well 300 milliseconds isn't very long.

Comment: The question is why when the div get's shown trough another function, this function also triggers.

Comment: We'd have to see your html to tell you that. Your click is bound to the document which means that code fires every time you click the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would avoid the `setTimeout` if you can, instead do this:

```
$("#info").fadeOut(300, function() {
  // Animation complete.
  $("#info").html("Select an Item");
});
```

Comment: Nice! Never knew you could do this, works great! Do you happen to know why even trough the if should not trigger this setTimeout executes?

Comment: We'd have to see your html to tell you that. Your click is bound to the document which means that code fires every time you click the page.

Comment: Oh I see, nevermind I understand the error now. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

I better solution is to use the delay function:

> $("#info").delay(1000).html("select an item").fadeOut(300);

References:

- http://api.jquery.com/delay/
- http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/